# Dereference pointer from unnamed namespace not working

Tags: c++, pointers, namespaces, dereference

For a Wii homebrew game engine I'm working on, I have this (shortened) script that handles printing text:

```cpp
#include <grrlib.h>

#include "graphics.hpp"

#include "Vera_ttf.h"

namespace {
    GRRLIB_ttfFont *font = GRRLIB_LoadTTF(Vera_ttf, Vera_ttf_size);
}

namespace graphics {
namespace module {

void print(const char *str, int x, int y) {
    GRRLIB_PrintfTTF(x, y, font, str, 12, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

} // module
} // graphics
```

This code compiles, however, when trying to call the `print` function above, nothing is rendered. Weirdly enough, removing the unnamed namespace and changing the `print` function to this:

```cpp
void print(const char *str, int x, int y) {
    static GRRLIB_ttfFont *font = GRRLIB_LoadTTF(Vera_ttf, Vera_ttf_size);

    GRRLIB_PrintfTTF(x, y, font, str, 12, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

works fine. However, I would like the font variable to be changeable by another `setFont` function. How can I achieve this?

Here's is the `GRRLIB_PrintfTTF` function code if anyone needs it: https://github.com/GRRLIB/GRRLIB/blob/master/GRRLIB/GRRLIB/GRRLIB_ttf.c

Comment: what's stopping you from putting the font pointer in a named namespace?

Comment: The version with anonymous namespace makes `font` a global, which means it's initialized before you enter `main` function, and the version with local `static` variable initializes it at the time of 1st function call. Maybe the former fails as there is library initialization that needs to be done before such function call?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tried that too, but it also didn't work. I probably should have mentioned that. It seems that it only works as a variable within the print function.

Comment: *This code compiles* -- All this means is that there are no syntax errors.  It has nothing to do with whether the program actually works according to plan.

Comment: By making it `static` it is called only once in that function -- the first time it is encountered.  If your goal is to call `GRRLIB_PrintfTTF` every time you call `print`, that isn't going to happen.

Comment: @Kaldrr You're probably right. How would I initialize the library before the font variable is defined though? GRRLIB uses a `GRRLIB_Init()` function for initialization.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It worked for me, the goal is that the `font` variable is only called once and then stored in memory. Preferably after becoming usable.

Comment: @HTV04 -- Note that the `C` tag is not relevant, since the code is C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got it, removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to initialize the library with GRRLIB_Init(), you can provide a similar init function to ensure that your variables are initialized after the library.

```
#include <grrlib.h>

#include "graphics.hpp"

#include "Vera_ttf.h"

namespace {
    GRRLIB_ttfFont *font = NULL;
}

namespace graphics {
    void InitGraphics() {
        font = GRRLIB_LoadTTF(Vera_ttf, Vera_ttf_size);
    }

namespace module {

void print(const char *str, int x, int y) {
    GRRLIB_PrintfTTF(x, y, font, str, 12, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

} // module
} // graphics
```

Call graphics::InitGraphics() after you call GRRLIB_Init()